# Dynamically import files from another directory

Tags: python-3.x, import

My input is a list of file names (as a list of variables) and I know the path to these files. Each file has a function called "test" and I have to call the "test" function from each of these files. The path is not my working directory. I need to be able to dynamically import these files.

I tried using importlib, but I get the following errors:

`import importlib`

```
importlib.import_module("..\..\foo", package=None)
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '..\\..\\x0coo'
```

```
importlib.import_module("C:\Users\Desktop\foo", package=None)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\foo'
```

How would I go about executing the function in a file, using the filename and path (both stored in variables)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but I solved this by first adding the path to
the module to sys.path:

```
>>import sys
>>sys.path.append('/path/to/module')
>>mod=importlib.import_module('my_module_name')
```

then you can call functions in that module like this

```
>>mod.myfunc(myargs)
```

or, if you have the function name in a python string like func='myfunctionname'
you can call it like

```
>>mod.__dict__[func](args)
```

Comment: I did come across adding it to the sys.path, and it does work yes. But if possible, I would prefer to do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see more code, but my first guess is that you need to replace \ with / in your Directory string, since \ escapes out of the string.

Comment: I replaced the \ with / but get the same errors as above. Absolute: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:/Users/Desktop/foo'. Relative: TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '../../boo'